# Group data set on 2 fields using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, group-by

I have some data coming from a database which I'd like to group in a particular way using LINQ but I'm struggling to get the grouping to work as desired.  Here are the details.

I have two C# classes which are my view models:

```
public class RawTrackerDataViewModel
{
    public int questionnaireId { get; set; }

    public string dateCompleted { get; set; }

    public int coachNodeId { get; set; }

    public int youngPersonNodeId { get; set; }

    public int questionIndex { get; set; }

    public int questionNodeId { get; set; }

    public int score { get; set; }

    public string coachName { get; set; }

    public string youngPersonName { get; set; }
}

public class ProcessedTrackerDataViewModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }

    public List<RawTrackerDataViewModel> data { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a web API controller pulling data from a database and mapping the data to the view models (using PetaPoco 'micro' ORM) like this:

```
    public List<ProcessedTrackerDataViewModel> GetData()
    {
        var db = ApplicationContext.Current.DatabaseContext.Database;
        var questionnaires = db.Query<RawTrackerDataViewModel>("SELECT Questionnaire.id AS questionnaireId, DATEDIFF(second,{ d '1970-01-01'},dateCompleted) AS dateCompleted, coachNodeId, youngPersonNodeId, questionIndex, questionNodeId, score, coachNode.[text] AS coachName, youngPersonNode.[text] AS youngPersonName FROM Questionnaire INNER JOIN Answer ON Questionnaire.id = Answer.questionnaireId LEFT JOIN umbracoNode AS coachNode ON Questionnaire.coachNodeId = coachNode.id LEFT JOIN umbracoNode AS youngPersonNode ON Questionnaire.youngPersonNodeId = youngPersonNode.id; ").ToList();
        var groups = questionnaires.GroupBy(x => x.questionnaireId);

        var data = new List<ProcessedTrackerDataViewModel>();

        foreach (var group in groups)
        {
            var newItem = new ProcessedTrackerDataViewModel();
            newItem.name = group.First().youngPersonName;
            newItem.data = group.ToList();
            data.Add(newItem);
        }

        return data;
    }
```

The data returned from the raw SQL query outputs something like this (all dummy data) just to give an idea of what we're dealing with:

[image]

When I call the controller via a front-end API call, it *almost* does what I need.  It pulls back the questionnaire data grouped by questionnaire id, like this (note, I've expanded one of the 'data' nodes to demonstrate the data being returned):

[image]

So far so good.

However, I now want to group the returned data based on the 'youngPersonNodeId' such that there would only be one object for 'Adam Greenall' containing a data array of 25 items, one object for 'Jamie Smith' containing 5 data items, one object for Zak containing 15 data items, etc.

I've tried grouping on both `questionnaireId` and `youngPersonNodeId` but that doesn't seem to make a difference:

```
 var groups = questionnaires.GroupBy(x => new { x.questionnaireId, x.youngPersonNodeId });
```

Could someone help with how to get this final grouping to work?

Many thanks.

Comment: you need to only group by `youngPersonNodeId` not `questionnaireId` like => `var groups = questionnaires.GroupBy(x => new { x.youngPersonNodeId });`

Comment: When you say, now you want to group by, do you mean in front-end with JS or in back-end with Linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to only group by `youngPersonNodeId` not on `questionnaireId`

```
var groups = questionnaires.GroupBy(x => new { x.youngPersonNodeId });
```

OR

```
var groups = questionnaires.GroupBy(x => x.youngPersonNodeId);
```

Comment: Can just do .GroupBy(x => x.youngPersonNodeId);